# I moved WordPress to root now posts go to 404

Tags: images, 404-error

http://deepdreamers.com/?p=495

I followed the instuction from WordPress on moving your blog. When I click to gothe next page, I get a 404 message and the same happens when I click on on any posts. My Images also won't work, even though they are all there in the uploads folder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you reset permalinks? Is your .htaccess writable?

[Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

If your host is yahoo.com, than you have more problems, because Yahoo hosting doesn't allow .htaccess files or permalinks.